# Is there certain language that would be considered improper for kid's manga/anime?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

I've noticed that anime geared at kids/teenagers (particularly shonen manga such as Naruto) seems to have language that translates to words that could be considered inappropriate in English (てめえ, きさま, etc.). I don't have a good enough sense of Japanese to tell whether these are more on the vulgarity range of "damn" or the f-word, but I was wondering if there's a certain set of words or threshold of words that would be considered inappropriate for anime/manga geared towards kids/teenagers (in the sense that a movie is rated R in the US if it has the f-word more than once, so the f-word is considered inappropriate for things geared at teenagers).

Comment: I suggest asking the same question over at Japanese.SE because this is one of those cases where both site's audiences can give good answers, and the overall knowledge doesn't intersect enough to consider it an unnecessary crosspost.

Comment: Well, kids in Japan do kancho (a poke using 2 fingers on the anus) which can be considered as a sexual harassment. So I guess the moral standard is different.

Comment: The two examples you gave are really versions of "you" that are impolite. The translators will have made that explicit by adding an insult to the translation.

Comment: Apart from the somewhat offensive second pronouns(kisama, temee), the word "kuso" which means "s-it" can be used as both compound word as well as an intensifier just like f-word, for e.g. "kusogaki" (little s-it/s--itty brat), "kuso atsui" (very hot = f--king hot). Another example is "Urusee"(shut up!). It's polite form is "Urusai". It's even rough form is "Uzai" which straight up means STFU!! in very angry tone. These words are usually used between close friends and not in public. (I am commenting because I am not qualified to answer as I am neither a speaker or learner of the language).